# Can Chrome Extensions Send Data to Remote Servers?

Tags: browser-extensions

Suppose an extension has a scary list of permissions like that below ("Site access: On all sites"):

[image]

Does this also give the extension permission to send my data to the author's servers via XHR?

I've read the documentation here but lack some background knowledge, so I am not sure in my interpretation:

[Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

After reading this, it seemed like the extension isn't allowed to send my data somewhere unless it has lines like the below in the manifest - is this correct?

```
"permissions": [
    "https://www.google.com/"
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After reading this, it seemed like the extension isn't allowed to send my data somewhere unless it has lines like the below in the manifest - is this correct?

This is incorrect.

XHR (and fetch) requires the `permissions` key to be set correctly [to avoid cross-origin restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#Host_permissions), but there are various ways to send data to a remote server, f.e. an auto-submitting form in a iframe, or loading a remote image with some parameters in the URL.